# Remote screen session

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, gnu-screen, remote

This is running me crazy:

I want to use 4 screen windows (within the same session) in a remote server (GCloud) to process 4 subjects in a parallel way.

Long story short:

1. I first create a detached session:

```bsh
gcloud compute ssh server --command "screen -dmS remoteSession"
```

2. And then I use the following to (remotely) add a new window to that session and start the process. The last `screen -X other` is to avoid screen of changing my current window (kind of create a window in a detached mode).

```bsh
gcloud compute ssh server --command "screen -x remoteSession -X screen -t window1 ping google.com; screen -X other"
```

*In this case I added the ping command instead of the huge command I use.

The problem is that this works when I type it in the shell, but not in the script. However, it works in the script when doing it on local (just doing the commands without the `gcloud compute blabla`).

The remote session seems to be created just fine. But when executing the second step it just prompts `No screen session found`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I already found out what was happening:

Somehow when I create the session it is created in `/run/screen/S-uname`, but when executing the second command it looks for sessions in `/run/screen/S-root` (without actually using `sudo` in either call).

The fast answer for me was to call the first command with sudo, allowing it to create a socket in `/run/screen/S-root`.

For more info you could take a look on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840007/how-can-i-fix-this-screen-php-no-screen-session-found)

Cheers!